HAPI FHIR - From CDA to FHIR by using StructureMap
I'm using hapi-fhir version 7.2.1 and I'm trying to convert a CDA document in FHIR resource by using FHIR Mapping language and StructureMap resources
I wrote this unit test
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = {FhirCda2FhirServerApplication.class})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Slf4j
public class CdaToFhirTests {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("fhirJsonParser")
  private IParser jsonParser;

  @Autowired private FhirContext fhirContext;
  @Autowired private DefaultProfileValidationSupport defaultProfileValidationSupport;
  private static IWorkerContext workerContext;


  @Test
  public void testCdaToFhirConverter() throws Exception {
    log.info("Test CDA to FHIR converter");

    // prePopulatedValidationSupport.addStructureDefinition(sd);
    HapiWorkerContext hapiWorkerContext =
        new HapiWorkerContext(fhirContext, defaultProfileValidationSupport);
    hapiWorkerContext.allStructures().stream()
        .forEach(
            structureDefinition -> {
              log.info(
                  "StructureDefinition type {} url {}",
                  structureDefinition.getType(),
                  structureDefinition.getUrl());
            });

    log.info("ALL STRUCT {}", hapiWorkerContext.allStructures());
    FileSystemResource cdaXmlResource = new FileSystemResource("ccda.xml");
    StructureMap structureMap =
        jsonParser.parseResource(
            StructureMap.class, new FileSystemResource("StructureMap.json").getInputStream());
    log.info("Loaded StructureMap {}", structureMap);
    StructureMapUtilities utils = new StructureMapUtilities(hapiWorkerContext);
    Element parsedCda =
        Manager.parse(hapiWorkerContext, cdaXmlResource.getInputStream(), FhirFormat.XML);
    Bundle target = new Bundle();
    utils.transform(null, parsedCda, structureMap, target);
    log.info("Bundle {}", jsonParser.encodeResourceToString(target));
  }
}

But when I execute it I get this error:

org.hl7.fhir.exceptions.FHIRFormatError: This does not appear to be a
FHIR resource (unknown namespace/name
'urn:hl7-org:v3::ClinicalDocument') at line 0 col 0
at
org.hl7.fhir.r4.elementmodel.ParserBase.logError(ParserBase.java:104)
at
org.hl7.fhir.r4.elementmodel.ParserBase.getDefinition(ParserBase.java:130)
at org.hl7.fhir.r4.elementmodel.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:181)
at org.hl7.fhir.r4.elementmodel.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:172)
at org.hl7.fhir.r4.elementmodel.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:143)
at org.hl7.fhir.r4.elementmodel.Manager.parse(Manager.java:67)  at
it.eng.pnt.fhir.cda2fhir.test.CdaToFhirTests.testCdaToFhirConverter(CdaToFhirTests.java:98)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)   at
java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1597)    at
java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1597)

I can't figure out what I'm missing. May anybody give me a tip?

If you are not specific about the technology you can use Microsoft FHIR Converter to convert from C-CDA to FHIR.
